# How conditionally sort array in one line?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to sort array only if it contains more than N elements, something like this:

```
$myArray | if $myArray.Count() > N -> | Sort-Object
```

How can I do this in one line?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an `if` statement and do everything in one line:

```
if ($myArray.Length -gt N) { $myArray = $myArray | Sort-Object }
```

But why would you wan't to do it? I would prefer it this way:

```
if ($myArray.Length -gt N) 
{ 
    $myArray = $myArray | Sort-Object 
}
```

You might wan't to find a solution without an if statement (only pipeline) but I don't see a reason for that.